# Configurar un JOptionPane (showMessageDialog) Trabajo con Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jbutton, joptionpane

amigos :). Quiero saber cómo configurar un **JOptionPane.showMessageDialog** . El problema es que yo necesito que la **"Ventana Mensaje"** se muestre después de apretar/ejecutar el botón **"Vender"** 5 veces exactamente (El botón **"Vender"** no ha sido configurado , sólo se cambió el color de letra y su nombre respectivo, tal como se ve en la imagen 1 e imagen 2 ".

Quiero dar a entender que la **"Ventana Mensaje"** me aparece al apretar/ejecutar sólo una vez el botón **"Vender"**

Yo necesito que la **"Ventana Mensaje"** aparezca después de apretar/ejecutar 5 veces exactamente el botón **"Vender"**.

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

En la imagen 3 muestro la **"Ventana Mensaje"**

[[image: Imagen 33]

Si es que necesito modificar el **JOptionPane.showMessageDialog** o intentar algún if else , ya lo hice pero de seguro me faltó algún código que no me sé.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda, espero sus respuestas:).

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).